# Is there any way make soft keyboard just hang under a specific button while inputting?

Tags: android, android-edittext, soft-keyboard

I have set `android:WindowSoftInput` as `adjustPan` but the button is covered by soft keyboard. And setting as `adjustResize`, the bottom layout will be above the soft keyboard which it is horrible.

Is there any way make soft keyboard just hang under the confirmed button while inputting?

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.edittextdemo.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/title" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Confirmed" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try This: http://www.davidwparker.com/2011/08/30/android-how-to-float-a-row-above-keyboard/

Comment: @VaishaliSharma Thanks. But the floating view is bottom linearlayout not the button when trying that.